# Switching between controllers with ros_control / controller_manager

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros-control, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an easy way to switch between different controllers for a single resource?
I would like to control a joint of my Gazebo model either by `effort_controllers/JointPositionController` or `effort_controllers/JointEffortController`. I want to switch between these controllers during runtime by pressing a joystick button.

Right now, I make 4 service calls:

1. Stop the current controller (by calling `controller_manager/switch_controller`)
2. Unload the current controller (by calling `controller_manager/unload_controller`)
3. Load the new controller (by calling `controller_manager/load_controller`)
4. Start the new controller (by calling `controller_manager/switch_controller` again)

Is there an easier way to do that, like loading both controllers at the same time and only start/stop the corresponding controllers by a single `switch_controller` call? As the [SwitchController Service](http://docs.ros.org/api/controller_manager_msgs/html/srv/SwitchController.html) has parameters for both start_controllers and stop_controllers, this seems to be supported somehow. But if I try to spawn both controllers in a launch file, I get a "resource conflict" error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259022/switching-between-controllers-with-ros_control-/-controller_manager/) by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 775 on 2017-04-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally found a way to simplify my approach. If you pass `--stopped` as an argument to the  [spawner](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#spawner), you can load a controller without starting it. So I ended up spawning the position controller as usual and the effort controller with the `--stopped` argument. Now I can switch from one controller to the other by just calling the `switch_controller` service.

I needed to add the following two lines to my launch file:

The code to switch from position controller to effort controller looks like that:

```
from controller_manager_msgs.srv import SwitchController
...
rospy.wait_for_service('/mybot/controller_manager/switch_controller')
try:
   switch_controller = rospy.ServiceProxy(
                       '/mybot/controller_manager/switch_controller', SwitchController)
   ret = switch_controller(['flipper_effort_controller'], 
                           ['flipper_position_controller'], 2)
   except rospy.ServiceException, e:
      print "Service call failed: %s"%e
```

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [itfanr](https://answers.ros.org/users/34867/itfanr/) on 2018-09-29**:
It is still through service call.
And  I tried cm.unload() function, but return 0(failed) always.

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2020-08-02**:
When my own controller was switched to another controller effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController, it was successful, but the robot arm fell down in simulation, does anybody know the reason?

**Comment by [chiku00](https://answers.ros.org/users/117886/chiku00/) on 2022-09-14**:
Did you add multiple hardware interfaces under transmissions for each joint? One for Position based controller and another for Effort based controller?